# Adding a property with the same value if has the same id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As what the title says, I wanted to add a **newPop: n** to an object if it has the same id in reactjs
I know this is easy but its giving me a hard time

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'john doe'
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'jane doe'
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'jane doe'
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'neil armstrong'
},
])
```

will be

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'john doe'
  newProp: 0,
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'jane doe'
  newProp: 1
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'jane doe'
  newProp: 1
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'neil armstrong'
  newProp: 2
},
])
```

My code, as you can see i'm terribly stuck.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
  if (data[i].id != data[i + 1].id) {
    const newData = {
      ...data[i],
      newProp: i,
    };
    setData(newData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the current value of name with previous value of name and keep track of your index.

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'john doe' }, { id: 2, name: 'jane doe' }, { id: 2, name: 'jane doe' }, { id: 3, name: 'neil armstrong' }, ];
let index = 0;
const updatedData = data.map((o,i,a) => {
  if(i && o.name !== a[i-1].name) {
    index++;
  }
  return {...o, newProp: index};
});
console.log(updatedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
const newArr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
  if (data[i].id != data[i + 1].id) {
    const newData = {
      ...data[i],
      newProp: i,
    };
    newArr.push(newData);
  }
}
setData(newArr);
```

That loops your array to a new array adding the index as newProp.
I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I misinterpreted it.

Comment: I edited it, could you try if that works. I noticed you set the state to the objects and not the renewed array